# Fail GitLab CI pipeline if any of the stage jobs are failed

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want a pipeline to fail if any job of the `build` stage are failed. In fact, it already works in that way but I have to wait all other jobs of the same stage to finish.

[image: One job failed but other jobs are still running]

Only then the pipeline will fail.

[image: Pipeline fails only when each job of the stage is finished]

Each job has `allow_failure` set to `false` so I have no idea how to fail pipeline immediately if one of the stage jobs fails. Any ideas?